# MongoDB and aggregation functions

Tags: mongodb

I've started playing with MongoDB and aggregation framework. What I'm trying to calculate is total value of expenses(333) and total value of subsistence(777). Any idea how that could be done? I've been playing with $unwind, $group, $project but got nowhere.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5442a4afc25282ab96463126"),
"expenses" : [
    {
        "name" : "a",
        "expenseValue" : 111
    },
    {
        "name" : "b",
        "expenseValue" : 222
    }
],
"subsistence" : [
    {
        "name" : "a",
        "valueSubsistence" : 333
    },
    {
        "name" : "b",
        "subsistenceValue" : 444
    }
]
```

}

I got that working  but had to fire two queries. One to unwind expenses, another one to unwind subsistence

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$expenses"},{$group:{_id:null,totalExpenses:{$sum:"$expenses.expenseValue"}}}])
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "totalExpenses" : 333
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$subsistence"},{$group:{_id:null,totalSubsistence:{$sum:"$subsistence.subsistenceValue"}}}])
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "totalSubsistence" : 777
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

The thing is I want to get that done in one query. When I unwind two arrays in one go I'm getting below, and from there I got nowhere so far

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$expenses"},{$unwind:"$subsistence"}])
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5442a4afc25282ab96463126"),
        "expenses" : {
            "name" : "a",
            "valueExpenses" : 111
        },
        "subsistence" : {
            "name" : "a",
            "valueSubsistence" : 555
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5442a4afc25282ab96463126"),
        "expenses" : {
            "name" : "a",
            "valueExpenses" : 111
        },
        "subsistence" : {
            "name" : "b",
            "valueSubsistence" : 444
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5442a4afc25282ab96463126"),
        "expenses" : {
            "name" : "b",
            "valueExpenses" : 111
        },
        "subsistence" : {
            "name" : "a",
            "valueSubsistence" : 333
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5442a4afc25282ab96463126"),
        "expenses" : {
            "name" : "b",
            "valueExpenses" : 222
        },
        "subsistence" : {
            "name" : "b",
            "valueSubsistence" : 444
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up your field names in your examples between styles of `valueSubsistence` and `subsistenceValue`, but assuming those are just typos and they're actually consistent, you're pretty close.  The trick is to do two separate `$group` stages where you carry forward the results of the first `$group` into the second using `$first`.

So something like this:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$expenses"},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        totalExpenses: {$sum: "$expenses.expenseValue"},
        subsistence: {$first: '$subsistence'}
    }},
    {$unwind: "$subsistence"},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        totalExpenses: {$first: '$totalExpenses'},
        totalSubsistence: {$sum: "$subsistence.subsistenceValue"}
    }},
])
```

Which gives output of:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "totalExpenses" : 333,
            "totalSubsistence" : 777
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```